# Reading from text file to array of object in java

Tags: java

I am working on Dijkstra algorithm. The program that I have read the data from a text file. the program works fine if I input the relation in the program but it does not work when I try to read the input from text file.

the input to the program in the program itself is as following:

```
 private static final Graph.Edge[] Arr = {
          new Graph.Edge("a", "b", 1),
          new Graph.Edge("a", "c", 1),
          new Graph.Edge("a", "f", 1),
          new Graph.Edge("b", "c", 1),
          new Graph.Edge("b", "d", 1),
          new Graph.Edge("c", "d", 1),
          new Graph.Edge("c", "f", 1),
          new Graph.Edge("d", "e", 1),
          new Graph.Edge("e", "f", 1),
       };
```

what I have tried to read from text file to be instead of this input is as following:
first, I count the number of the line to be the size of the array:

```
public static int count;
public static void countLines(String file) throws IOException
    {
    LineNumberReader  lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File(file)));
    lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    Dijkstra.count=lnr.getLineNumber() + 1; 
        lnr.close();
}
```

The function that will do the reading from the text file and saving the data to the array is as following:

```
public static Graph.Edge[] readTextFile(String fileName) {

    String line = null;
    Graph.Edge[] Gr=new Graph.Edge[Dijkstra.count-1];
    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("txt2.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        int i=0;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\t+");
            String s = tokens[0];
            String e = tokens[2];
            Gr[i] =new Graph.Edge(s, e, 1);
            i=i+1;
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
    }
    return Gr;
    }
```

these functions and the main are within some class called Dijkstra. the whole code is as following:

```
package shortestPath;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Dijkstra {

/*private static final Graph.Edge[] Arr = {
          new Graph.Edge("a", "b", 1),
          new Graph.Edge("a", "c", 1),
          new Graph.Edge("a", "f", 1),
          new Graph.Edge("b", "c", 1),
          new Graph.Edge("b", "d", 1),
          new Graph.Edge("c", "d", 1),
          new Graph.Edge("c", "f", 1),
          new Graph.Edge("d", "e", 1),
          new Graph.Edge("e", "f", 1),
    };*/
    public static int count;
    //public static Graph.Edge[] GRAPH = new Graph.Edge[count] ;

    public static void countLines(String file) throws IOException
    {
    LineNumberReader  lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File(file)));
    lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    Dijkstra.count=lnr.getLineNumber() + 1; //Add 1 because line index starts at 0
    // Finally, the LineNumberReader object should be closed to prevent resource leak
    lnr.close();
    //return Dijkstra.count;
    }

    public static Graph.Edge[] readTextFile(String fileName) {

    String line = null;
    Graph.Edge[] Gr=new Graph.Edge[Dijkstra.count-1];
    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("txt2.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        int i=0;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\t+");
            String s = tokens[0];
            String e = tokens[2];
            Gr[i] =new Graph.Edge(s, e, 1);
            i=i+1;
        }

        // Always close files.
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
    }
    //return Dijkstra.GRAPH;
    return Gr;
    }


       private static final String START = "12";
       private static final String END = "18";

       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
          countLines("hsa00072.txt"); 
          Graph.Edge[] GRAPH=readTextFile("hsa00072.txt");
          Graph g = new Graph(GRAPH);
          g.dijkstra(START);
          g.printPath(END);


          //g.printAllPaths();
       }
    }

    class Graph {
       private final Map<String, Vertex> graph; // mapping of vertex names to Vertex objects, built from a set of Edges

       /** One edge of the graph (only used by Graph constructor) */
       public static class Edge {
          public final String v1, v2;
          public final int dist;
          public Edge(String v1, String v2, int dist) {
             this.v1 = v1;
             this.v2 = v2;
             this.dist = dist;
          }
       }

       /** One vertex of the graph, complete with mappings to neighbouring vertices */
       public static class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex> {
          public final String name;
          public int dist = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // MAX_VALUE assumed to be infinity
          public Vertex previous = null;
          public final Map<Vertex, Integer> neighbours = new HashMap<>();

          public Vertex(String name) {
             this.name = name;
          }

          private void printPath() {
             if (this == this.previous) {
                System.out.printf("%s", this.name);
             } else if (this.previous == null) {
                System.out.printf("%s(unreached)", this.name);
             } else {
                this.previous.printPath();
                System.out.printf(" -> %s(%d)", this.name, this.dist);
             }
          }

          public int compareTo(Vertex other) {
             return Integer.compare(dist, other.dist);
          }
       }

       /** Builds a graph from a set of edges */
       public Graph(Edge[] edges) {
          graph = new HashMap<>(edges.length);

          //one pass to find all vertices
          for (Edge e : edges) {
             if (!graph.containsKey(e.v1)) graph.put(e.v1, new Vertex(e.v1));
             if (!graph.containsKey(e.v2)) graph.put(e.v2, new Vertex(e.v2));
          }

          //another pass to set neighbouring vertices
          for (Edge e : edges) {
             graph.get(e.v1).neighbours.put(graph.get(e.v2), e.dist);
             //graph.get(e.v2).neighbours.put(graph.get(e.v1), e.dist); // also do this for an undirected graph
          }
       }

       /** Runs dijkstra using a specified source vertex */ 
       public void dijkstra(String startName) {
          if (!graph.containsKey(startName)) {
             System.err.printf("Graph doesn't contain start vertex \"%s\"\n", startName);
             return;
          }
          final Vertex source = graph.get(startName);
          NavigableSet<Vertex> q = new TreeSet<>();

          // set-up vertices
          for (Vertex v : graph.values()) {
             v.previous = v == source ? source : null;
             v.dist = v == source ? 0 : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
             q.add(v);
          }

          dijkstra(q);
       }

       /** Implementation of dijkstra's algorithm using a binary heap. */
       private void dijkstra(final NavigableSet<Vertex> q) {      
          Vertex u, v;
          while (!q.isEmpty()) {

             u = q.pollFirst(); // vertex with shortest distance (first iteration will return source)
             if (u.dist == Integer.MAX_VALUE) break; // we can ignore u (and any other remaining vertices) since they are unreachable

             //look at distances to each neighbour
             for (Map.Entry<Vertex, Integer> a : u.neighbours.entrySet()) {
                v = a.getKey(); //the neighbour in this iteration

                final int alternateDist = u.dist + a.getValue();
                if (alternateDist < v.dist) { // shorter path to neighbour found
                   q.remove(v);
                   v.dist = alternateDist;
                   v.previous = u;
                   q.add(v);
                } 
             }
          }
       }

       /** Prints a path from the source to the specified vertex */
       public void printPath(String endName) {
          if (!graph.containsKey(endName)) {
             System.err.printf("Graph doesn't contain end vertex \"%s\"\n", endName);
             return;
          }

          graph.get(endName).printPath();
          System.out.println();
       }
       /** Prints the path from the source to every vertex (output order is not guaranteed) */
       public void printAllPaths() {
          for (Vertex v : graph.values()) {
             v.printPath();
             System.out.println();
          }
       }

    }
```

The text file is as following:

```
12  ECrel   15
15  ECrel   18
11  ECrel   12
12  ECrel   14
11  ECrel   14
11  ECrel   18
14  maplink 17
```

the problem is whenever I want to find the path like from node 12 to node 18 it will say 18(unreached) even if there is a path but it will not return the path. in case of the input in the program it works fine and return the path. the problem is only appears when trying to read from the text file.

Comment: Code snippets are for code which can be run by browser like HTML/JS/CSS. For Java use `Code Sample` which icon on editor looks like `{}`.

Comment: Have you tried comparing `Arr` to `GRAPH` and seeing if they are different? Do you get an array with the same values?

Comment: Vivin Paliath I have only GRAPH or Arr. they are the same but I use Arr when I input in the program and I will not call readTextFile function because it will read from the text file.

Answer (score 0):

There is something very strange going on here.  I'll babble along as I work through it.

I get randomly different results (sometimes your program works as you wanted, sometimes not).  Often they are different depending on whether I am running in debug mode or not.

So . . . it's time to look for a source of randomness.  Clearly you're not using randomness directly/intentionally.  So we should look somewhere else for the randomness.

I think I see two potential sources of randomness.

1. When you're traversing the NavigableSet, it's doing a lot of comparing equal values at first.  That's necessary and makes sense, but it might lead to randomness, since it doesn't have to pick one particular order of how to present the elements to you.
2. You also use Maps in your algorithm, and there are no promises about what order their entrySets come back in.

My guess is that your algorithm is actually sensitive to the order in which things are presented to it.  I haven't dug in enough to know which bits might be the problem, but maybe this section goes two different directions if two equally good routes are presented to it in different orders:

```
            if (alternateDist < v.dist) { // shorter path to neighbour found
                q.remove(v);
                v.dist = alternateDist;
                v.previous = u;
                q.add(v);
            }
```

and possibly one of those routes never leads to the destination you're looking for.

I would actually suggest getting out bits of paper and writing the vertices on them, and shuffling them whenever your algorithm calls for an iterator over map EntrySets.

My suspicion for why this works when reading from the source and fails when reading from code:  different random seeds.  That's it.  It's technically prone to the same failure in both cases, it just happens to pick a working path in one JVM scenario and a non-working path in the other JVM scenario.

Sorry this is kind of fuzzy and really long.  Maybe it will help.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought I may have some problem with the functions that I have written or with the calling of these function or passing the parameters. Thank you again.